# One login to lead to two different pages to two different users

Tags: php

I am trying to make a login portal which leads to two different pages, the connection should lead according to the user it's logging in, the problem it's no matter what username is entered, as long as it is in the database, it leads to the last location written on code, i do not know what could be wrong:

```
<?php
// connection to host and database
$host="localhost";
$username="dbusername";
$password="dbpass";
$db_name="dbname";
$tbl_name="members";

// connection
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

//username and password sent from
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

//escape strings and stripslashes
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and   password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

//to count tables
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// **no matter the user it logs in, they will land in page2.php**
if($count==1){
    ($myusername == 'user1'){
        header('location:page1.php');
}
elseif($myusername == 'user2'){
    header('location:page2.php');
}
else {
    echo "wrong username or password";
}
```

Another thing that goes on is that i cannot connect safely to either page1.php or page2.php through a `session_start();`, since it does not need to log in to enter the page, it only requires to know the link, this is what i write on the beginning of page1.php before the html starts:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!$myusername == 'user1'){
    header("location:main_login.php");
}
?>
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: there is error after if($count==1).

Comment: First correct the condition which you have written ($myusername == 'user1').. You forgot to add if..

Answer (score 0):

Why we encourage good indentation of code:

```
if($count==1)
{
 if ($myusername == 'user1') // you forgot an if here
 {
     header('location:page1.php');
 }
else if ($myusername == 'user2')
 {
     header('location:page2.php');
 }
else 
{
     echo "wrong username or password";
}
}//another closing bracket here
```

Answer (score 0):

In page1.php, how do you initialize the `$myusername` variable?

You should try some examples for a basic login first. It seems you are following [this](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html) but I believe

a. That example is bad.

b. You edit the code without understanding the logic behind.

Please read the session examples at [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) or php [manpage](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).

**login page**

```
if (isset($_REQUEST["username"])) {
  /* 
    usename & password verification here 
    you need to set $_SESSION["username"] in this code 
  */

  if ($_SESSION["username"] == "user1") {
    header("Location: page1.php");
  } else if $_SESSION["username"] == "user2") {
    header("Location: page2.php");
  }   
} else {
  /* login form here */
}
```

**page1.php**

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
  header("Location: login.php");
} else {
  /* content of page 1 here */
}
```

**page2.php**

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
  header("Location: login.php");
} else {
  /* content of page 2 here */
}
```

Comment: in order to have the page accessed after the session was correctly input i use `if(!_$myusername == 'user1'){"header("location:main_login.php")}` but if you have the link of page1.php you access it from anywhere without a required login.

Answer (score 0):

No need to count the results really, as you will need to redirect the script regardless.  So, depending on the 'username', redirect to a specific page, or an error page.

```
switch ($myusername) {

    case 'user1':
        $redirectPage = 'page1.php';
        break;

    case 'user2':
        $redirectPage = 'page2.php';
        break;

    default:
        $redirectPage = 'error.php';
}

header("Location: $redirectPage");
exit;
```

Comment: Great, this does redirects to each username to a page each but the password becomes irrelevant if you know the user, can you `switch` in a way the user has to match to their respective password?

Comment: Then each 'page' must check that the current user has access to that particular page - or redirect.